# Как исправить отображение ListView с Bottom navigation menu?

Tags: java, android-studio, xml, listview, bottom-navigation-view

не хватило скила пользования гуглом, потому я здесь, уж извините)
Как сделать так, чтобы при прокрутке в самый низ ListView становился позицию выше панели нижней навигации, а не как сейчас, когда в самом низу его перекрывает эта самая панель?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Home2Activity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >



        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/search_button_style"
            />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/activiti_home__listView"
            />


    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/filterico"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_filter_list_24px" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/voiceico"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:alpha="0.74"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_keyboard_voice_24px" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorGray"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_colors"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorOrange"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation_vacancy_list" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Покажите свой лейаут - без этого сложно что либо сказать

Comment: Добавил код к вопросу.

Answer (score 0):

Основная ошибка в верстке состоит в том, что у вас есть корневой лейаут, внутри которого есть `LinearLayout`, который должен занимать весь корневой лейаут (`match_parent`), далее есть несколько `ImageView`, которые и перекрывают низ.

Вариантов решения масса, например так: верстку изменить на 2 `LinearLayout`, в первом поместить `ListView` и ничего больше, второй прижать к низу и туда разместить ваши кнопки. Причем в обоих `LinearLayout` применить по вертикали `wrap_content`